# PHP: Grab an image from a stream (in an img tag) but if it's not there, i don't want the img tag written. How?

Tags: php, image, refactoring, stream

I currently have code like this in a web based file called 'view_file.php' to grab an image from an internal network.

```
<img src="put_file.php?type=<?=$TN_TYPE;?>&path=<?=$TN_PATH;?>&filename=<?=$TN_FILENAME;?>" />
```

The 'put_file.php' script allows access to an internal server that we don't want to expose to the internet. This script checks to see if an image is available and if it is, sends an image header and then uses `readfile()` to stream the image to the 'view_file.php' page.

The problem is if there isn't an image available, instead of streaming a temporary 'spacer.gif' i want to not have the img tag written at all.

Any Ideas how to do this?
I'm thinking maybe move the img tag into the 'put_file.php' script, but how to mix strings and steams?

Comment: What value is stored under $TN_FILENAME ?

Comment: The filename is something like '6045125.jpg'

Comment: If i understand correctly you cannot check if the image exists in view_file.php because it doesn't have access to the internal server. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done simply I think.

- You could make a call to `put_file.php` in PHP, see what it returns, and if it returns an empty value (or a `404` header or whatever) refrain from writing the img tag. Obvious con: The request is made twice, and it complicates the script.
- You could create the image element in JavaScript depending on the result of an Ajax call to `put_file.php`. Obvious con: Doesn't show up straight after loading, and needs JavaScript.

Both these options *could* be reduced to making one request by piping the results of the testing request into [base64-encoded `data:` URI's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but that is highly incompatible (no IE support) and bloats the page on browser side (the image data plus 33% overhead would be present straight in the source code, or the JavaScript memory, respectively). I wouldn't recommend it.

If at all possible, I personally would stick with the `spacer.gif` solution.

**Update:** One other idea, if it's just that you don't want the images to appear, would be sending a `404` header when the image isn't there, and utilizing the `onerror` event of the `img` tag to, say, do a `<img onerror='this.style.display = "none"'>`. Requires Javascript, of course. The error event seems to be fully supported in all browsers (reference [here](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/sprache/eventhandler.htm#onerror), german only sorry, but you'll see the icons :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use base64 to do what you want.

http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html